# Folders in public directory no longer directly accessable in laravel 4

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-4, laravel-routing

This seems to just have happened but I have an image server with folders in the public directory that contain images. i.e. /public/files/10031/users/me.jpg and when I try to access them through the URL mysite.com/files/10031/user/me.jpg I get a route error now. I am using the image server to show images to my web server and my web site. Both are running Laravel 4.2. Any ideas how to access them?

I am running Laravel on Ubuntu and Nginx.

Comment: What's the error message? Did it work before?

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file and routes.php

Comment: It did work before. There is no .htaccess since I am running on Nginx.

My only routes:
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::get('/download/org_file/{file_id}/{directory}/{org_id}','UploadController@download');

Comment: http://images.petpalmanager.com/files/10031/photo/UEIFexcOa4owfgBzNnL.jpg give you Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Can you try and run a check on file permissions in the folder(s) you are trying to reach, just to be sure you even have those.

Comment: Weird. I update the permissions again and that worked. Not sure how the permissions were set wrong again. Thanks!